How to setup HTTPS in netHttpBinding in wcf?
I have to create a sample project in which client and server communicate with netHttpBinding over https(wss). My code and configuration is working perfectly fine with http binding. But when I an using HTTPS then it gives error as followed

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://localhost:8080/NetHttp. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.'

Code and Configurations are as followed

IHTTPService.cs (ServiceContract)

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace NetHttpBindingPocSvc
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IDuplexServiceCallBack))]
    public interface IHttpService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        void SendMessage(string message);
    }

    public interface IDuplexServiceCallBack
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void ReceiveMessage(string message);
    }
}


Service Implementation

    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class HttpService : IHttpService
    {
        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message from client received: {message}");

            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IDuplexServiceCallBack>();
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback.ReceiveMessage("Message has been received");
            }
        }


Hosting of the service

 internal class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var serviceInstance = new ServiceHost(typeof(NetHttpBindingPocSvc.HttpService));
         serviceInstance.Open();
         Console.WriteLine($"Service is up and running");
         Console.ReadLine();
     }
 }


App.Config (Server)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add scheme="http" binding="netHttpBinding" />
            <add scheme="https" binding="netHttpsBinding" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <services>
            <service name="NetHttpBindingPocSvc.HttpService" behaviorConfiguration="netHttpBindingBehaviour">
                <endpoint address="" binding="netHttpBinding" contract="NetHttpBindingPocSvc.IHttpService" bindingConfiguration="netHttpBinding">
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8080/NetHttp" />
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8081/NetHttp"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <netHttpBinding>
                <binding name="netHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:40:00" sendTimeout="00:40:00"
                         transferMode="Buffered" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="20000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:40:00" enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="netHttpBindingBehaviour">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>


Client side Code (Service consumption)

   internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var message = Console.ReadLine();
        string url = $"wss://localhost:8080/NetHttp";
        var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(new DuplexMessageReceiver());
        NetHttpService.HttpServiceClient client = new NetHttpService.HttpServiceClient(instanceContext);
        client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new Uri(url), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("localhost"));
        //client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localhost");
        client.Open();
        client.SendMessage(message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public class DuplexMessageReceiver : NetHttpService.IHttpServiceCallback
    {
        public void ReceiveMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}


Client Side config

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netHttpBinding>
                <binding name="NetHttpBinding_IHttpService">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    </security>
                    <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always" />
                </binding>
            </netHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="wss://localhost:8080/NetHttp" binding="netHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetHttpBinding_IHttpService" contract="NetHttpService.IHttpService"
                name="NetHttpBinding_IHttpService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

I am not sure what wrong I have done in this. The same configuration of certificate is working fine for net.tcp binding

does https://localhost:8080/NetHttp/mex work in web browser when service is running? without certificates errors ?

mex is not working in browser with https and http both,
with http://localhost:8081/NetHttp the Service reference can be generated

Try modifying it here:
<client>
            <endpoint address="wss://localhost:8080/NetHttp" binding="netHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetHttpBinding_IHttpService" contract="NetHttpService.IHttpService"
                name="NetHttpBinding_IHttpService" />
<identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
</identity>
        </client>

Remember to use the certificate.

Thanks for your response, I tried but unfortunately it didn't work,
Certificate is installed on the system. In Server the certificate is added in Behavior and at client it is added by Endpoint Identity while creating client object.

Is the app.config code on your client edited by yourself or automatically generated through the Service Reference? The reason I'm giving that answer is because the client configuration file generated after my client references the service exists. It is used to verify the certificate. I'm curious why you don't have this code...

I have also tried hosting the server on IIS, if I host the service on IIS then it works perfectly fine.
